# Set language to Chinese Simplified (Zh-Hans) doesn't work on IOS9

Tags: swift, localization, ios9, chinese-locale, setlocale

i'm trying to set the locale to zh-Hans and change my placeholder to simplified Chinese text.

i'm using the sample from: https://github.com/anishparajuli555/SMSLocalization

when i try to set to other language.. it working.. but not working for simplified Chinese. i hope someone can advice me on this.. i'm new to ios development.. is it the country code issues or the language code.?? because i run the project no error prompt..

Thank you in advance...

here is my code:

**LanguageManager.swift**

```
override init() {

    let english = Locale()
    english.initWithLanguageCode("en", countryCode: "gb", name: "United Kingdom")

    let finnish  = Locale()
    finnish.initWithLanguageCode("fi", countryCode: "fi", name: "Finland")

    let chinese = Locale()
    chinese .initWithLanguageCode("zh-hans", countryCode: "zh-Hans", name: "China")

    self.availableLocales = [english,finnish,chinese]
 }
```

in my **ViewController.Swift** i added another @IBAction to set the locale to zh-Hans and get the bundle

```
@IBAction func showAlertInChinese(sender: AnyObject){
    LanguageManager.sharedInstance.setLocale("zh-Hans")
    bundle = LanguageManager.sharedInstance.getCurrentBundle()
}
```

this is my **Main.strings (Chinese(Simplified))**

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Name"; ObjectID = "5Pu-4M-URI"; */
"5Pu-4M-URI.text" = "Name";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Finnish"; ObjectID = "Ezp-NI-f7w"; */
"Ezp-NI-f7w.normalTitle" = "Finnish";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "English"; ObjectID = "HBX-eg-qyo"; */
"HBX-eg-qyo.normalTitle" = "English";

/* Class = "UITextField"; placeholder = "Password"; ObjectID = "LS8-g7-7Vf"; */
"LS8-g7-7Vf.placeholder" = "Password";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Chinese"; ObjectID = "UZ0-ba-gcI"; */
"UZ0-ba-gcI.normalTitle" = "Chinese";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Login"; ObjectID = "ZYz-eL-ISh"; */
"ZYz-eL-ISh.normalTitle" = "Login";

/* Class = "UITextField"; placeholder = "userName"; ObjectID = "tGt-sW-fB7"; */
"tGt-sW-fB7.placeholder" = "userName";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Password"; ObjectID = "xCL-5A-88z"; */
"xCL-5A-88z.text" = "Password";
```

while in my **Localizable.strings** i have set the simplified Chinese text value

```
KUserName = "用户名";
KPassword ="密码";
KName = "名称:";
KPwd = "密码:";
KLogin = "登录";
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason , zh-Hans and zh-Hant are treated as zh

[It look strange to me , I've never encounter this before [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZwYL.png)

So you can only use "zh" for this project instead of zh-Hans/zh-Hant , I manage to make it work if I am using "zh"